# Infinite blocking polling in Observable

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am using a library that allows me to poll for events (blocking), until there are no more events (in which case it returns `nil`).

I am tempted to implement the observable like so:

```
private func createObservable() -> Observable<MyEvents> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let myPollingObject = PollingObject()

        while let event = try myPollingObject.poll() {
            observer.onNext(event)
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Where the `while` loop finishes when there are no more events (and `poll()` returns `nil`).

However, the `while` loop means that I never `return Disposables.create()`, which is an issue.

Is there a more reactive way to implement that? I don't really feel like putting the `while` loop in a thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your loop in a dispatch queue. You should also handle errors properly and notify the subscriber when it's completed. Also some way to cancel would be nice...

```
func createObservable() -> Observable<MyEvents> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let myPollingObject = PollingObject()
        var canceled = false
        DispatchQueue.init(label: "poller").async {
            do {
                while let event = try myPollingObject.poll(), !canceled {
                    observer.onNext(event)
                }
                if !canceled {
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            }
            catch {
                observer.onError(error)
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create { canceled = true }
    }
}
```